# fair to middling (what's the part of speech of 'fair'?)

Tags: word-usage, parts-of-speech

> 'fair to middling' means just average

'fair' has many parts of speech.

What's the usage of 'fair' here?

Comment: What do _you_ think it is?

Comment: @ColinFine I like your question :D. 'fair' here doesn't have an article like 'a/an/the' so it's evidently not a noun; 'to middling' means 'to' is a preposition and 'to middling' would be 'an adverbial phrase' which modifies whatever the parts of speech are; the focus is at 'to middling' not fair, so I logically think the 'fair' is an adverb emphaszing '(to) middling': quite to middling

Comment: Obviously ***fair*** must be the same "part of speech" as ***middling***, and I think you could reasonably assume they'll be the same POS as ***average***, if that helps. Also consider a common usage context:: *"How are things going?" - "[Things are going] Fair to middling"*.

Comment: This kind of usage of 'fair' is difficult for foreigners to identify its part.

Comment: See [this explanation](https://writingexplained.org/idiom-dictionary/fair-to-middling). Another source says it's tautology as  _fair_ and _middling_ mean the same!

Comment: I'm very dubious of that explanation, @KateBunting. I believe it is an originally humorous expression, where the fact that _fair_ and _middling_ mean the same thing was part of the humour.

Comment: Why didn't you add your analysis in the question? Add more details, tell us where you  found the expression etc. Continue asking low-quality questions and you might face a question ban in the not too distant future....

Comment: @Mari-LouA Easy on me. There is nothing in life. When the time comes, everyone dies. My question is short and needs more research but probably not that low in quality.

Comment: It's the system, not the community, which automatically bans users from posting content, users whose questions are frequently downvoted and/or closed.

Answer (score 1):

"Fair" is an adjective.  It is used either as a modifier "a fair wind" or as a complement with a linking verb.  It isn't a noun (a fair is like a temporary market, not relevant) Nor a verb (it don't head a clause) and the verbal sense is about making smooth, aligned, streamlined etc.

One can form a compound adjective phrase with "to". For example "I like my curry warm to hot." It means "somewhere between warm and hot.

At least part of the irony in this expression is that "fair" and "middling" are both adjectives with roughly the same meaning.

Comment: I'm curious: Would you consider "to" a conjunction here? A preposition? An adverb? (And why?)

Comment: @MarcInManhattan I would consider 'to' as a preposition because its meaning is '(from) A to B even if the B is not a noun.

Comment: I'd go with a conjuction, though it is a good question.

Comment: I'm leaning toward preposition (with B as a kind of nominalized adjective), but yeah I don't think that there's any perfect answer.